# How do I find the first checkbox in Capybara?

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I'd like to find the first instance of a checkbox using the capybara dsl. Anyone know how to do that?

I thought perhaps it'd be this, but it didn't work:

```
find('input:first', :type => 'checkbox')
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming Capybara.default_selector is set to CSS then:

```
find("input[type='checkbox']")
```

If you're using XPath it will be different.

**Update (June 2013):** as @tmg points out, the behaviour for Capybara 2 has changed.

Comment: Will this find the very FIRST checkbox?

Comment: Yes. Alternatively: all("input[type='checkbox']").first

Comment: In Capybara 2 find will raise **Capybara::Ambiguous** if more than one element matches.  Instead use: first("input[type='checkbox']") or find a more unique locator to use with find.   See: [first](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#first-instance_method)

Answer (score 11):

Just to point out [tmg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1760776/tmg)'s right way to find the **first** checkbox

```
first("input[type='checkbox']")
```

If you want to find **n-th** checkbox (25-th for example):

```
find(:xpath, "(//input[@type='checkbox'])[25]")
```

But it's often better to use **within** to narrow your searching area

```
within 'div.div_class' do
  find("input[type='checkbox']")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The least [flaky](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/write-reliable-asynchronous-integration-tests-with-capybara) way to find the first checkbox could be:

```rb
find("input[type='checkbox']", match: :first)
```